# Play Youtube video in background using youtube player api

Tags: android, background, youtube-api

I have successfully played youtube video using `youtube player api`. But I need to run it in background on back button press.I have googled a lot but found nothing Please help me to achieve this.Thanks in advance

here is my code-

```
public class FullscreenDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener,

        YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {
//  private MyPlaybackEventListener myPlaybackEventListener;
    private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

    private LinearLayout baseLayout;
    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    public YouTubePlayer player;
    private Button fullscreenButton;
    private CompoundButton checkbox;
    private View otherViews;

    private boolean fullscreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_demo);
        baseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        fullscreenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_button);
        checkbox = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.landscape_fullscreen_checkbox);
        otherViews = findViewById(R.id.other_views);
        playerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        this.player = player;
        setControlsEnabled();
        // Specify that we want to handle fullscreen behavior ourselves.
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
        player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("avP5d16wEp0");
        }
        int controlFlags = player.getFullscreenControlFlags();
        setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
        controlFlags |= YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
        player.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
        player.play();


    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return playerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        player.setFullscreen(!fullscreen);
    }



    private void doLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams playerParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) playerView
                .getLayoutParams();
        if (fullscreen) {
            // When in fullscreen, the visibility of all other views than the
            // player should be set to
            // GONE and the player should be laid out across the whole screen.
            playerParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            playerParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            otherViews.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            otherViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams otherViewsParams = otherViews
                    .getLayoutParams();
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                playerParams.width = otherViewsParams.width = 0;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                otherViewsParams.height = MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.weight = 1;
                baseLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            } else {
                playerParams.width = otherViewsParams.width = MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                playerParams.weight = 0;
                otherViewsParams.height = 0;
                baseLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            }
            setControlsEnabled();
        }
    }

    private void setControlsEnabled() {
        checkbox.setEnabled(player != null
                && getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        fullscreenButton.setEnabled(player != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        fullscreen = isFullscreen;
        doLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // System.out.println(getScreenOrientation());
        doLayout();
    }

    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements PlaybackEventListener {

          private void updateLog(String prompt){
        System.out.println(prompt);
          };

          @Override
          public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
           updateLog("onBuffering(): " + String.valueOf(arg0));
          }

          @Override
          public void onPaused() {

           updateLog("onPaused()");
          }

          @Override
          public void onPlaying() {
           updateLog("onPlaying()");

          }

          @Override
          public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
           updateLog("onSeekTo(): " + String.valueOf(arg0));
          }

          @Override
          public void onStopped() {
              player.loadVideo("avP5d16wEp0");

              player.cueVideo("avP5d16wEp0");
              player.play();
           updateLog("onStopped()");
          }

         }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for that topic and I found that there is not an official way and won't be according to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=729) on Google code.

In it they propose that you create a player.

Hide the player.

Mute the player.

Call seekTo() with your videoId and optional offset.

Wait for state change to "playing".

Press pause.

Call seekTo(originalOffset, false).

Unmute the player.

Show the player. (or whatever).

It maybe doesn't do what you need but maybe you can change what you need to achieve your goal using this method.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that youTube player will stop once and the Activity/Fragment is in the background, I need it to keep playing

Comment: I don't know much about what I am going to say now. How about using a service which handles the buffering then pass it to the activity. I'll be looking into it with you and if anyone finds something, he would post it here.

Comment: maybe this can help you.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/3sEonjD0Nqk

Comment: even if it was possible to pass the video stream, we need the player to continue playing after onPause has been called, the Activity/Fragment has to stay alive all the time.

Comment: onPause() doesn't have an impact on the service. Meaning keep the video stream in service and the pass what you want from it whenever you want to the activity while keeping the service open. At the end of the video you may choose to clear the service stream and close the service.

Answer (score 0):

Check the state of the player when the back button is clicked, i think it will be in paused and or buffering state. you can try patching it on the listeners, onbuffering listener, call playvideo/ change state to playing video. I tried and had it worked for iOS, dont know the platform limitations on this context.

Comment: It is possible however that will make the player to stop and play again. and I need it to keep on playing like the screen is in the foreground.

Comment: the video is not stopped but paused, so it plays from where its paused, try working am sure it works @david

Comment: I know it paused I've already implemented that, I need the video to keep playing and not pause for ~second and than play.

Comment: Yeah the little pause, i observed it. its inevitable