# Keeping Youtube video running while changing activities

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I’m using the Youtube API in an app I built. It works well as long as I stay in one activity - once I switch to another activity the video stops playing.

How do I keep the video playing in the background of the activity I switched to?

I saw one option for an answer in this question:
[Play Youtube video in background using youtube player api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258004/play-youtube-video-in-background-using-youtube-player-api)

But is there a different option without having to deal with possible lag? Like the Youtube app video minimising while swapping between activities.

Thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell, every app that offered this has either been removed from the app store or been forced by Google to remove the functionality. Something to keep in mind if you're building the app for public use.

Comment: @Lilienthal, so the only option I'd be left with is the one from the similar question? Thanks