# Android: Play youtube video using YouTubePlayer in background

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I was trying to measure some parameters from YouTube android api in foreground. But was trying to also implement it in background for periodic measurements.

I am using service as my background base, and trying to initialize YouTube player in it. But it requires an activity(or fragment activity) to initialize it. So I also created an invisible activity in service but of no use.

So my question is, is there any way to initialize YouTube player in a service?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258004/play-youtube-video-in-background-using-youtube-player-api)?

Comment: Yes, but of no use. Now I was searching for some other way and I found that youtube use exoplayer in it. So was trying to use it.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/smedic/Android-YouTube-Background-Player/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/smedic/tubtub/BackgroundAudioService.java